# How many symmetries does the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality have?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

The symmetries of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $(x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2)(y_1^2 + \cdots + y_n^2) \ge (x_1y_1 + \cdots + x_ny_n)$, as a subgroup of the symmetric group on the $2n$ letters $x_1,\ldots, x_n, y_1,\ldots, y_n$, is generated by transpositions of the form $(x_i \, x_j)$, $(y_i\, y_j)$ and $(x_i \, y_i)$ where $i,j=1,\ldots, n$.

What is the order of this subgroup?

Comment: Looks to me like the only symmetries are on indices swapping $x$ and $y$ terms simultaneously. So the symmetry group is $S_n$, with order $n!$  (And you're missing a $^2$ or some square roots.)

Comment: If it's generated by those transpositions, then $x_i$ can be swapped with $y_j$ via $(x_ix_k)(x_ky_j)$, so I don't see why it wouldn't just be $S_{2n}$.